# The compact layout in the new navigation hides the number of results

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

The new navigation has the option to display posts in the compact or expanded layouts:

> [image]

When you are using the expanded layout, you get the result count to the right:

> [image]

When you choose the compact layout though, there is no indication of how many results are found:

> [image]

The missing count had me confused for quite a while, and it is embarassing how long it took for me to find it (and how I had to discard a partial question here asking where the count had gone!)

Comment: I just came to Meta to post this, except I didn't realize there was a way to get it back and I was going to post about how horrible this lack-of-feature is for jobs like checking tag usage.